# Making Custom Post Type Hierarchical Permalinks Flat

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

So basically I've been trying to make my permalinks look like this:

/recipes/postid/postname

rather than what has the potential to become this:

/recipes/postparent/postparent/postparent/postparent/postname

Users have the ability to create posts on the front end that are children of other posts. This can go on and on and I don't want the permalinks to be insanely long.

I was able to remove all parent postnames from the permalink using the code below. However, this doesn't work if someone creates a post name that already exists.

I would like to be able to change the permalink to include the post id in it so this doesn't happen but I can't figure it out. I appreciate any help!

Here is the code:

```
function Recipes() {

$labels = array(
'name'                  => _x( 'Recipes', 'Post Type Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'singular_name'         => _x( 'Recipe', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Recipe' ),
'menu_name'             => __( 'Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'archives'              => __( 'Recipes Archives', 'recipes' ),
'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'all_items'             => __( 'All Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'add_new'               => __( 'Add Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'new_item'              => __( 'New Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'update_item'           => __( 'Update Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'view_item'             => __( 'View Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'search_items'          => __( 'Search Recipes', 'recipes' ),
);
$args = array(
'label'                 => __( 'Recipes', 'Recipes' ),
'description'           => __( 'Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'labels'                => $labels,
'supports' => array(
  'title',
  'thumbnail',
  'comments',
  'editor',
    'revisions'),
'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'recipes-tag' ),
'hierarchical'          => true,
'public'                => true,
'show_ui'               => true,
'show_in_menu'          => true,
'menu_position'         => 5,
'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-editor-ul',
'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
'can_export'            => true,
'has_archive'           => true,
'exclude_from_search'   => false,
'publicly_queryable'    => true,
'capability_type'       => 'page',
'show_in_rest'       => true,
'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'recipes' ),

);
register_post_type( 'recipes', $args );

add_rewrite_rule(
        '^recipes/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=recipes&name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

}

add_action( 'init', 'Recipes', 0 );


function bvt_recipes_flatten_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( 'recipes' != $post->post_type ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    $uri = '';
    foreach ( $post->ancestors as $parent ) {
        $uri = get_post( $parent )->post_name . "/" . $uri;
    }

    return str_replace( $uri, '', $post_link );
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'bvt_recipes_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE

I figured it out. Here are the changes in case anyone else runs into this problem.

```
function Recipes() {

$labels = array(
'name'                  => _x( 'Recipes', 'Post Type Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'singular_name'         => _x( 'Recipe', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Recipe' ),
'menu_name'             => __( 'Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'archives'              => __( 'Recipes Archives', 'recipes' ),
'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'all_items'             => __( 'All Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'add_new'               => __( 'Add Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'new_item'              => __( 'New Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'update_item'           => __( 'Update Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'view_item'             => __( 'View Recipe', 'recipes' ),
'search_items'          => __( 'Search Recipes', 'recipes' ),
);
$args = array(
'label'                 => __( 'Recipes', 'Recipes' ),
'description'           => __( 'Recipes', 'recipes' ),
'labels'                => $labels,
'supports' => array(
  'title',
  'thumbnail',
  'comments',
  'editor',
    'revisions'),
'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'recipes-tag' ),
'hierarchical'          => true,
'public'                => true,
'show_ui'               => true,
'show_in_menu'          => true,
'menu_position'         => 5,
'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-editor-ul',
'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
'can_export'            => true,
'has_archive'           => true,
'exclude_from_search'   => false,
'publicly_queryable'    => true,
'capability_type'       => 'page',
'show_in_rest'       => true,
'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
// 'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'recipes' ),

);
register_post_type( 'recipes', $args );

add_rewrite_rule(
         'recipes/([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)?$',
         'index.php?post_type=recipes&name=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]',
         'top' );

}

add_action( 'init', 'Recipes', 0 );



function change_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'recipes' ){
        return home_url( 'recipes/'. $post->post_name .'/'. $post->ID );
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}


add_filter('post_type_link', 'change_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```